# How to find related nodes per relationship depth?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to come up with a query for the following data model in neo4j.

```
Readable-[:readBy]-Student
    |
 [:owns]
    |
Readable-[:readBy]-Student
    |
 [:owns] -----------------------------------------
    |                                             |
Readable-[:readBy]-Student           Readable-[:readBy]-Student
    |
 [:owns]
    |  
Readable-[:readBy]-Student
```

The query:

Return all students by distance their from the first `Readable` in a map.

```
MATCH (:Readable{name:'book'})-[:owns*0..3]-(r:Readable)
MATCH (r)-[:readBy]-(s:Student)
RETURN s
```

That query seems to correctly traverse the tree and find each student at each distance, but I can't seem to record the distance for each student to return at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `LENGTH` function.

```
MATCH p = (:Readable{name:'book'})-[:owns*0..3]-(:Readable)-[:readBy]-(s:Student)
RETURN s.name, LENGTH(p);
```

Edit: To get a map by length (key) and collection of students (value):

```
MATCH p = (:Readable{name:'book'})-[:owns*0..3]-(:Readable)-[:readBy]-(s:Student)
WITH LENGTH(p) AS len, COLLECT(s) AS students
RETURN {length: len, students: students};
```